# Finding the standard deviation with certain information

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

Is one able to get to a sample standard deviation with the following pieces of information?

Mean, Median, Count, IQR

We can assume it's a normal distribution.

Comment: Not exactly, but in a normal distribution the difference between 25th and 75th percentiles is about  $1.349\sigma.$  So with a large enough sample one could come close. In R: `set.seed(1214); x = rnorm(1000, 50, 7); sd(x); IQR(x)/1.349` returns $S = 7.480212; S \approx 7.63742.$ Somewhat closer, I suppose, by doing a simulation to get a better approximate ratio of sample SD to sample IQR for the specific sample size. `

Comment: Thank you @bruceET !